# Formatting .dart files (flutter) in vsCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I can't seem to set the automatic formatter up.

I have both the Dart and Flutter vsCode extensions.

Here is my settings.json file:

```
{
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
  "debug.openDebug": "openOnDebugBreak",

  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },

  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",

  "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [80],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.flutter",
    },
  
  "dart.flutterHotReloadOnSave": "always",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

I want the formatter to add `;` and `,` at the end of lines and also to add/remove spacing and indenting where needed. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: The Dart formatter will not add semicolons and commas for you  The formatter [primarily changes only whitespace](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ#why-does-the-formatter-only-touch-whitespace-by-default).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.flutter",
```

Formatting is done by the Dart extension (since it's not specific to Flutter), so this should be set to `Dart-Code.dart-code` rather than `Dart-Code.flutter`.

Comment: Thanks man. This helped. Also, it's very important to add trailing commas while writing flutter code. Formatting won't happen unless those commas are added.

Comment: Formatting does work without trailing commas - trailing commas only affect _how_ the code is formatted (see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting#using-trailing-commas)